# Trip Advisor Rating count returns 'None' - Python Webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am tyring to scrape the Trip-Adivors number of reviews in Yellowpages.

Here is the complete code from start to bottom.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import re

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://google.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5'
}

url = ("https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/restaurants?page=1")
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

organic_results = soup.find_all('div', class_='result')

for item in organic_results:

    TA_rating_count = item.find("span", class_ = "ta-count")
    if TA_rating_count is not None:
        number = TA_rating_count.text
        TA_rating_count = number.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
    else:
        TA_rating_count = None
    
    print(TA_rating_count)
```

Output:

```
None
```

Expecting to return it with the number of reviews in trip Advisors in text format.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. See: [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405791) you should provide the minimal HTML of the site you're trying to scrape.

Comment: it is not finding this element. You can print the items in the `for loop` to verify this...

Comment: use selenium, the tag '//span[@class="ta-count"]' which you are trying to fetch is getting loaded from JavaScript . hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your `response` / `soup` to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.*

The information you are looking for is stored in an `attribute` of the element not in its text - It will be rendered dynamically by the browser, but `requests` is not a browser and will only provide the static information from response.

Select your element and get its attribute value:

```
for e in soup.select('.info-section:has(h2)'):
    if rating:= e.select_one('.ratings').get('data-tripadvisor'):
        print(json.loads(rating).get('count'))
    else:
        print('no info')
```

###### Example

```
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://google.com',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5'
}

url = ("https://www.yellowpages.com/los-angeles-ca/restaurants?page=1")
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('.info-section:has(h2)'):
    if rating:= e.select_one('.ratings').get('data-tripadvisor'):
        print(json.loads(rating).get('count'))
    else:
        print('no info')
```